# What are these interruptions in queueing networks?

Tags: queueing

I'm interested in modifications of Kendall queueing networks where agents in the network can be arbitrarily (according to a distribution or a deterministic function) moved from one part of the network to another part of the network. I try to provide some examples below to explain what I mean.

## Examples

### Redirected While Waiting

John is on a waitlist for a surgery and expects to have his surgery completed next month. However, a comorbidity arises and he is immediately placed

### Leaves Service Network While Waiting

Sarah is waiting in line to get into the club. Noticing that the line is not shortening at an appreciable rate, she infers that the club is probably full. She decides to leave the lineup and go home.

### Blocked At Service Due To Agent Attribute

Kailey has been waiting for her turn on a roller coaster, and waits until it is her turn to board. But when she is asked for her ticket she realizes that it has become lost or stolen. She is rejected service, and goes back to the booth where she can purchase more tickets before deciding where to go next.

### Incomplete Service After Being Redirected

Andrew goes for an MRI appointment. Part-way through the procedure he goes into cardiac arrest. He is rushed to the ER and cardiac surgery is performed. While he started the MRI appointment, he needs to reschedule another visit to complete it.

## Question

What are these sorts of interruptions called in the literature?